# Getting 'a' value from 'Maybe a' return type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have a Haskell function `eval :: WExp -> Memory -> WValue` with a bunch of different instances of itself for different cases. For now, knowledge about `WExp`, `Memory`, and `WValue` is not relevant. My problem is that, for a specific instance of `eval`, I am using a `lookup` function, which takes the parameter of `eval` (a string in this case) searches a list of key-value pairs for that string. Note that this `lookup` function is not the one included in the Prelude; it is self-defined within the .hs file. If the string is found, the value associated with it is returned, but if it is not found, `Nothing` is returned. Because of the `Nothing` case, the type of `lookup` is actually `Maybe a`, where `a` would be a `WValue` in this case. Because `eval` would return a `Maybe WValue`, the compiler obviously complains that the type is not `WValue`.

I thought that there might be some kind of general method to extract the `a` value from any function that returns `Maybe a`.

Comment: There's the `maybe` function in `Prelude`, and a couple more useful ones in `Data.Maybe`.  What do you want to happen when the `lookup` returns `Nothing`?

Comment: Another common pattern is to use `fmap` to turn a function that works on normal values into one that works on `Maybe` values.

Comment: Thanks @bheklilr, I'll look into `fmap`. And the `Nothing' return is just to give `eval` something explicit to do when the input string is not found in the list that `lookup` is searching through.

Comment: The point is, what if your expression uses a variable which is not defined by your memory? In that case, I guess your lookup would return `Nothing`. What `WValue` would you return then as the result of the expression evaluation?

Comment: There are certain elements in the memory that are listed as `("|", undefined)`. The reason for this is unimportant, but there are times where when the value would obviously be undefined, and so `Nothing` would be returned in these cases. That being said, the specific instance of `eval` that I am talking about would be called by the user, not from any other functions. Because I'm not making this for any commercial purpose, it's safe to assume the user would search for a string that the user would know already exists. So, in this perfect world, a proper key would always be returned.

Comment: @UnworthyToast, partial functions are widely condemned by Haskell programmers. If the user searches for something that's not there, they don't want to see your program crash with some internal error; they want it to return a failure message and let them try again. That's done by letting the `Maybe` bubble all the way out to your user interface, where it can be handled gracefully. (Or, in some cases, turning the `Maybe` into something else like `Either` or `Error` or whatever that can hold on to detailed information about the problem.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Do this

```
do
   input <- getUserInput
   result <- lookup input structure
   case result of
     Just a -> putStrLn $ "I'm so happy you chose "++show a++"."
     Nothing -> putStrLn $ "So sorry; "++input++" is not a valid option."
```

#### Don't do this

```
do
   input <- getUserInput
   result <- lookup input structure
   case result of
     Just a -> putStrLn $ "I'm so happy you chose "++show a++"."
     Nothing -> error $ input ++ " is not a valid option."
```

This is bad because your program just goes splat if the user input is wrong.

#### Really don't do this

There is a function called `fromJust` that attempts to pull a value out of a `Maybe` and throws an error if it finds `Nothing`. It looks like

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust (Just a) = a
fromJust Nothing = error "Oops, you goofed up, fool."
```

This makes it hard to see what went wrong.

#### And really, *really* don't do this

But if you want to play with fire, you can try it just for fun. This will attempt to get a value out of a `Maybe` and crash real hard if it finds `Nothing`. By "crash real hard" I mean you'll get a segmentation fault if you're lucky, and you'll publish your private keys on the web if you're not.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-unused-binds #-}

module Unsafe.FromJust (unsafeFromJust) where

-- Clear sign of bad news
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)

-- This creates a "closed kind" with types
-- 'JustType and 'NothingType. You could just
-- define datatypes called JustType and NothingType,
-- but this makes the intent clearer.
data MaybeType = JustType | NothingType

data M (t::MaybeType) a where
  -- The order of these constructors must not
  -- be changed, because this type must look,
  -- at runtime, exactly like a Maybe
  N :: M 'NothingType a
  J :: a -> M 'JustType a

-- A safe sort of fromJust for M.
fromJ :: M 'JustType a -> a
fromJ (J a) = a

-- Really, seriously unsafe.
unsafeFromJust :: Maybe a -> a
unsafeFromJust m = fromJ (unsafeCoerce m)
```

Comment: in your first two examples maybe you want `show input` in the `Nothing` case since `a` is defined?

Comment: Wow, I ran that and all my private keys were published. I demand a refund. >:(

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, your full refund of US $0.00 has been electronically transferred to your account.

Answer (score 14):

The function you are looking for is `maybe` defined in Prelude.

You need to decide on what to return if the expression is Nothing. Lets say you want to get empty string `""` for Nothing. Then the following will let you get out of Maybe boxes.

```
Prelude> maybe "" id (Just "hello")
"hello"
Prelude> maybe "" id (Nothing)
""
```

Answer (score 7):

If you know that the lookup is successful, and that the `Maybe a` is actually `Just a`, you can simply pattern match:

```
let (Just val) = lookup ...
```

and there you have your `val::a` out of your `Maybe a`. Note that this is unsafe code which will ungracefully throw an error if `lookup` returns a `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you got yourself into a quagmire because the type of your `lookup` says that it could fail. Haskell forces you in this case to deal with the possibility that such a failure will occur. This is the case if `lookup` returns `Nothing`.

If you are *really* sure that `lookup` never fails (maybe because you preprocessed and type-checked the program, or you really trust it :) ) you could use `fromJust` from `Data.Maybe`. Note that is is really just a band-aid solution because `fromJust` *will* produce a (Haskell) runtime error on its own if called with `Nothing`.