# Just Number in Haskell - get the value

Tags: json, haskell, numbers, option-type

I looked into a way to get the raw value of a value that's in a JSON response body that I'm getting from an API.

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_String, key)
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_Number, key)
import Network.Wreq

conditionsQuery2 :: String -> String
conditionsQuery2 company =
"https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" ++ company ++ "/quote"

main :: IO()
main = do
    print "What's the company name?"
    company <- getLine
    r <- get (conditionsQuery2 company)
    putStrLn "The full company's name is: "
    print $ r ^. responseBody . key "companyName" . _String 
    putStrLn "And the stock price is: "
    print $ r ^? responseBody . key "latestPrice" . _Number
```

The issue I'm getting is with the last line `print $ r ^? responseBody . key "latestPrice" . _Number` because the value I'm getting is: `Just 166.9` for a given stock price (just an example). I understand that there is a `Maybe` type in Haskell, but in the context of getting a number value from a JSON response, is there a way to easily access that value? Or do I need to write something along the lines of what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706843/getting-a-value-from-maybe-a-return-type-in-haskell) with `Just a -> putStrLn $ "the value: " ++ show a`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What should happen in case it is `Nothing` (for instance because the JSON is invalid, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, you need to pattern match and handle the `Nothing` case (or e.g. use a helper function like `maybe`)

Comment: If the value will never be `Nothing`, you can use `^?!` instead of `^?`.